# Shrink a polygon to a line

Tags: image-processing, vector-graphics

Is there any library or algorithm to convert a polygon to a line by shrinking it. I am passing points of my polygon and I want the points of the line as output.

[image]

Comment: This is not easy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton

Comment: For any polygon or will they always be vaguely narrow concave structures like this?  Also are you looking for the midline or just one of the edges?  Finally, does it need to be able to convert back?  (please add answers in your question, not to this comment)